# Library or method for filtering images based on colours they have

Tags: jquery

I am interested in a way to filter images based on what colours they have.
E.g. when I select "green" ,then will appearing images that have the green colour inside their pallete.This should be done automatically,there should be no "tagging" of photos before.Is there any jquery or php library that can do that?
thanks

Comment: `This should be done automatically,there should be no "tagging" of photos before` - why? I mean, why can't you tag indexed images?

Comment: Because my site will have user generated content and I don't want to force them to tag images with colours.

Comment: But why do you want to force _them_ to tag images with colors? Can't you tag these images automatically instead? )

Comment: @raina77ow ,how can I tag them automatically?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cannot perform image analysis.

To do what you want you'd have to load each image into Canvas an perform some sort of statistical analysis on the bitmap data. This would likely be to too slow to be useful on any more than a few images.

Comment: Hm,I have seen this here http://search.theknot.com/search/?q=yellow and would like to add into my site.It should be a method to do it...